# c# start new process in window mode

Tags: c#, process, console

My C# application starts a Process with a console app.

The process is starting correctly and it's visible in the Task Manager, but the process is running without a window.

How can I run a console application with its own window?

My code:

```
 p_info.UseShellExecute = true;
 p_info.CreateNoWindow = false;
 p_info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
 Process.Start(p_info);
```

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with `UseShellExecute` and other properties?

Comment: The simple explanation is that it is not a console mode application.  Use dumpbin.exe /headers and look at the reported "subsystem".  It must say "Windows CUI" (note C, not G) to make it a console app.  Java apps can be screwy.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a sample to launch a visible console application from another application

```
var p_info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = @"archi\ConsoleApplicationtest\ConsoleApplicationtest\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplicationtest.exe"
};
Process.Start(p_info);
```