# How do I start a new process with a new window, from a console application?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a Console Application in C# that starts and manages other console applications.

When I use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start('anotherapp.exe");`, the output from the process is printed to my current console application.

In this instance, I'm **not** able to redirect the output as some of the applications forcibly control their stdout.

How do I force the new process to start & use it's own window/console?

The following have provided no difference in results:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593572/c-sharp-start-new-process-in-window-mode

Comment: @esnezz Thanks, I've updated my question appropriately - these flags have not changed the result as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from the process is printed to its own window only. After starting that process, the managing program is ends/closed. So, the called application is only currently opened.

Try `Console.Read()` in calling application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\repos\check\check\bin\Debug\check.exe";  // just for example, you can use yours.
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    process.Start();
    Console.Read();
}
```

I tried this code to call another application. check.exe is opened and displayed its value seperately.

We can also use `Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)`

`process.WaitForExit();` can also be used after `process.Start()`. This will wait for new application to close.

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely no idea how this worked, but it did! Do you have any more reasoning as to why this works?

Comment: The main thread in invoking application starts new application by process.start() and won't wait for the new application to close. So, after starting new application, the main thread ends. In order to stop closing the invoking app, we used Console.Read(). It'll wait for the user input to this application

We can also use Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)