# Run Multiple Console apps in separate windows

Tags: c#

I have a console application that runs another console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.FileName = $"path to another console app";
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

I need to start the second console app in another window, but currently, it will run the second one inside the main console app and will show the text inside the main app.

How to start other console apps in a new window?

Comment: like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593811/5174469) ?

Comment: You need to do some equivalent of calling `CreateProcess` with the [`CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) set. I don't think there's a built-in managed way to do it so you'd be looking at P/Invoke.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could you please provide a more detailed information as an separate answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working for me on Windows with .NET 5. Note that .NET Framework has different default settings for starting processes.

```cs
using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = $"path to another console app";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.Start();
}
```